# Do we really need an [engine] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now we have a few questions with the [engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) tag (35, to be precise).
This tag seems to be ambiguous at best (is it a piston engine, a jet engine, a turboprop engine, an electric engine (motor), etc.)

Most of the existing questions seem like they're better under [piston-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piston-engine) or [turbine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbine) (possibly with [turboprop](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turboprop) or [jet-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jet-engine) attached for good measure), so can anyone think of a case where we would want just [engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine)?

Answer (score 6):

I really can't see a need for [engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine), so if no objections come up I'll retag these posts at some point next week and let [engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) die a quiet death.

Comment: I agree with that. The [question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/700/65) for which [tag:engine] was created a [tag:turbine] tag. Hence it is redundant.

Comment: @Farhan I have mixed feeling about [tag:turbine] too - is it a Jet? Turboprop? APU? Turbocharger? (technically the turbocharger is a turbine!) - but I definitely *actively dislike* [tag:engine].

Comment: I have found one [question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9144/19) that makes valid use of the generic engine tag. The rest should be retagged. I already did a couple retags.

Answer (score 3):

When I wrote the [tag wiki](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/engine/info) for engine, I said that a more specific tag is always better but I did mention some cases where it could be appropriate:

> Because there are several very different engine types for aircraft,
>   you should avoid using this tag if you can use a more specific one
>   like [jet-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jet-engine) or [piston-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piston-engine).
>
> Use this tag for questions where the specific engine type isn't
>   important, isn't known or where multiple engine types are being
>   compared.

It looks like none of those cases have really come up yet and of course we can't be sure that they ever will, but I do think there's at least a potential use for it and I suspect that people will keep using it, especially people with little knowledge about aircraft.

But having said that, I think we should focus on actual questions and not on potential ones, so I think it's fine to clean up the existing tags as far as possible and see what happens.